# switch to the AdSense API version 2

Tags: adsense-api

After October 12, the existing AdSense API version 1.4 is not supported, and I tried to switch to the AdSense API version 2, so it is difficult. We would appreciate it if you could provide more details about the update process.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/release_notes) to get a sense of everything that is different in v2.

If you're using a Google client library, there are updated examples for v2 [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/v2).